# How to extract or print out specific columns of data from its result of sum in the multiple simulation in R?

Tags: r, simulation

I ran a simple simulation multiple times as follows and was wondering if there is a way to extract the values of outcome.

```
Time <- 100   # number of simulation periods
Ni <- 100    # number of objects
MC <- 100   # number of multiple simulations

#parameter setting
gamma <- 2  
phi <- 0.1   
Pbar <- 0.01  

set.seed(15)


#allocating aggregate variables / initial conditions
YY <- matrix(data=0,ncol=MC,nrow=Time)      
AA <- matrix(data=0,ncol=MC,nrow=Time)
BB <- matrix(data=0,ncol=MC,nrow=Time)    

for (mc in 1:MC) {
  
  if (mc<=50) {
    set.seed(mc)
  } else {
    set.seed(mc-50)
  }
  
  #allocating individual variables / initial conditions
  A <- matrix(data=1,ncol=1,nrow=Ni)        
  K <- matrix(data=1,ncol=1,nrow=Ni)        
  B <- matrix(data=0,ncol=1,nrow=Ni)        
  I <- matrix(data=0,ncol=1,nrow=Ni)         
  P <- matrix(data=0,ncol=1,nrow=Ni)        
  Y <- matrix(data=0,ncol=1,nrow=Ni)         
  Z <- matrix(2*runif(Ni)+Pbar,ncol=1,nrow=Ni) 
  
  # main program 
  for (t in 2:Time) {
    
    if (mc>50 & t>50) {
      rbar <- 0.01
    } else {
      rbar <- 0.02
    }
    
    I <- gamma * Z 
    I[I<0] = 0
    K <- K + I 
    Y <- phi * K 
    B <- K - A 
    P <- 2*runif(Ni)+ Pbar 
    r <- rbar + rbar*(B/A)^rbar
    Z <- P * Y - r * K 
    A <- A + Z 
    YY[t,mc] <- sum(Y) 
  } 
}

# compute MC median and plot. 
YY1 = matrix(data=0,nrow=Time,ncol=1)

for (t in 1:Time) {
  YY1[t] = median(YY[t,1:50])
}

YY2 = matrix(data=0,nrow=Time,ncol=1)

for (t in 1:Time) {
  YY2[t] = median(YY[t,51:100])
}

plot(2:Time, YY1[2:Time],type="l", col ='blue')
lines(2:Time, YY2[2:Time],type="l",col='red')
```

And I got this plot.

[image]

My question is:
How can I print out the values of `Y`s that correspond to different if-conditions(`rbar=0.02` or `rbar=0.01`) at `Time = 80` and `Time = 100` (instead of `YY1` or `YY2`).

FYI, in fact I could get one of `Y` by typing `Y`, but I am not sure if this values correspond to which `rbar` condition. Is there any way I can get both `Y` values at `T=100`(or `T=80`) by either manipulating my codes or new command?

Comment: `YY1[c(80,100)]` the first value is the value for `Time=80` and the second is for `Time=100` same goes for `YY2`

Comment: if you the value of the `YY` matrix then `YY[c(80,100),1:50]` first row is used for `YY1` at `time=80` .....

Comment: @Abdessabour-mtk, thanks but all I want to obtain is `Y` values at `t=100` or `80` under each different `rbar` condition. FYI, `YY= sum(Y)`. I was wondering if there's a way to get those `Y` values separately from `YY1 (rbar=0.02)` and `YY2 (rbar=0.01)`at `t=100` or `80`.